# state don't change on first click

Tags: reactjs, boolean, state, render

my page state doesn't change on first click. i set `useState` name redirect, to change page state to boolean value, but on first click it doesn't work. if you go back to page from second click it's ok and it works.

```
const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState();
 const PluNum = (plu) => {
    const product = posts.find(
      (item) => item.plu.toString() === plu.toString()
    );
    if (product) {
      setRedirect(true);   // here on first click state don't change to true
      console.log(redirect)
      const prevproduct = items.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
      setSelectedpr( product  );
      setNum("")
  }
  
  else if(!product){
    setRedirect(false);  // here on first click state don't change to false
    console.log(redirect);
    toast.error("plu is wrong");
}
}
```

i put this condition in html code

```
    {redirect ? 
        <Link to="/pluitem" className="digit" onClick={()=>PluNum(num)}>submit</Link> 
        : 
          <div className="digit" onClick={()=>PluNum(num)}>submit</div>
        }
```

i test code below but it did not work too

```
setRedirect((prevState) => [prevState, true]);
```

```
setRedirect((prevState) => [...prevState, true]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: no it does not works